# group barchart code in R

Tags: r, graph, bar-chart

I am a total beginner on R and I am trying to create a group barchart using the following data about breast cancer frequency and mortality

[image]

I'm trying to get the age categories along the X-axis and the frequencies along the Y-axis. 
Any help would be great.

Comment: It is easier if you rearrange your data (i.e with `melt` (`reshape package`)). There are many examples on stackoverflow or google for that. Just try "barchart in R".

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of data. A useful answer is much easier to get if you info in a more useful format; for examplei f you could add the results of `dput(subdf)` to your question. Thanks